# Reports in Doc Format in openerp

Tags: doc, odoo, odt

Is there any library which convert odt format to doc format...Actually i need to print the reports in doc format?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it, but [PyODConverter](http://www.artofsolving.com/opensource/pyodconverter) looks good. Also check out this general discussion of [converting file formats using OpenOffice](http://www.oooninja.com/2008/02/batch-command-line-file-conversion-with.html).

Answer (score 0):

Well I have Used the relatorio based module pxgo reports its working perfecly fine.

Answer (score 0):

I am using aeroo reports in my production server and it works great on 6.1 install.Just select the output format of the report from the menu.

You can generate .xls .doc .ods .html and textonly .txt reports, download module from launchpad and access forum from alistek.com for forum.